# jQuery attr vs prop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, prop

Now this isn't just another *What's the difference question*, I have [done some tests(http://jsfiddle.net/ZC3Lf/)](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC3Lf/) modifying the `prop` and `attr` of `<form action="/test/"></form>​`  with the output being:

> **1) prop Modification test**
>   Prop: `http://fiddle.jshell.net/test/1`
>   Attr: `http://fiddle.jshell.net/test/1`
>
> **2) Attr Modification test**
>   Prop: `http://fiddle.jshell.net/test/1`
>   Attr: `/test/1`
>
> **3) Attr then Prop Modification test**
>   Prop: `http://fiddle.jshell.net/test/11`
>   Attr: `http://fiddle.jshell.net/test/11`
>
> **4) Prop then Attr Modification test**
>   Prop: `http://fiddle.jshell.net/test/11`
>   Attr: `http://fiddle.jshell.net/test/11`

Now I am confused about a couple of things, as far as my knowledge goes:
**Prop:** The value in its current state after any modifications via JavaScript
**Attr:** The value as it was defined in the html on page load.

Now if this is correct,

- Why does modifying the `prop` seem to make the `action` fully qualified, and conversely why does modifying the attribute not?
- Why does modifying the `prop` in `1)` modify the attribute, that one makes no sense to me?
- Why does modifying the `attr` in `2)` modify the property, are they meant to be linked that way?

---

## Test Code

**HTML**

**JavaScript**

```
var element = $('form');
var property = 'action';

/*You should not need to modify below this line */

var body = $('body');
var original = element.attr(property);

body.append('<h1>Prop Modification test</h1>');
element.prop(property, element.prop(property) + 1);

body.append('Prop: '+element.prop(property)+'<br />');
body.append('Attr: '+element.attr(property)+'<hr />');

//reset
element.prop(property, original);
element.attr(property, original);

body.append('<h1>Attr Modification test</h1>');
element.attr(property, element.attr(property) + 1);

body.append('Prop: '+element.prop(property)+'<br />');
body.append('Attr: '+element.attr(property)+'<hr />');

//reset
element.prop(property, original);
element.attr(property, original);

body.append('<h1>Attr then Prop Modification test</h1>');
element.attr(property, element.attr(property) + 1);
element.prop(property, element.prop(property) + 1);

body.append('Prop: '+element.prop(property)+'<br />');
body.append('Attr: '+element.attr(property)+'<hr />');

//reset
element.prop(property, original);
element.attr(property, original);

body.append('<h1>Prop then Attr Modification test</h1>');
element.prop(property, element.prop(property) + 1);
element.attr(property, element.attr(property) + 1);

body.append('Prop: '+element.prop(property)+'<br />');
body.append('Attr: '+element.attr(property)+'<hr />');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Unfortunately none of your links work :(

Some insight though, `attr` is for all attributes. `prop` is for properties.

In older jQuery versions (<1.6), we just had `attr`. To get to DOM properties such as `nodeName`, `selectedIndex`, or `defaultValue` you had to do something like:

```
var elem = $("#foo")[0];
if ( elem ) {
  index = elem.selectedIndex;
}
```

That sucked, so `prop` was added:

```
index = $("#foo").prop("selectedIndex");
```

This was great, but annoyingly this wasn't backward compatible, as:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

has no attribute of `checked`, but it does have a property called `checked`.

So, in the final build of 1.6, `attr` does also do `prop` so that things didn't break. Some people wanted this to be a clean break, but I think that the right decision was made as things didn't break all over the place!

Regarding:

> Prop: The value in it's current state after any modifications via JavaScript
>
> Attr: The value as it was defined in the html on page load.

This isn't always true, as many times the attribute is actually changed, but for properties such as checked, there isn't an attribute to change, so you need to use prop.

References:

http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/

http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-16-and-attr

Comment: Link to test was on "done some tests" above I'll make it more visible, but here it is anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/ZC3Lf/

Comment: I find a question, if the attribute is customized, not DOM properties, prop() returns `undefined`, and attr() works well.

Answer (score 3):

There is a clear case to see differences between .prop and .attr

consider the HTML below :

```
<form name="form" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="action" value="myvalue" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<pre id="return">
</pre>
```

and the JS below using jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#return").append("$('form').prop('action') : " + $('form').prop('action') + '\r\n');
    $("#return").append("$('form').attr('action') : " + $('form').attr('action') + '\r\n');
    $("#return").append("document.form.action : " + document.form.action);
});
```

creates the following output:

```
$('form').prop('action') : [object HTMLInputElement]
$('form').attr('action') : #
document.form.action : [object HTMLInputElement]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this

```
console.log(element.prop(property));
console.log(element.attr(property));
```

and it outputs as below

```
http://fiddle.jshell.net/test/
/test/
```

this may indicates that the `action` is normalized only when it is **read** with `prop`.

Comment: I don't think so, as otherwise the output in `2)` would be normalized!

Comment: @Hailwood It won't, because you got `/test/` when access to `attr`, and then set `/test/1` to `attr`, which is attr of the element. There aren't any procedure that triggers normalization.

Comment: I am confused as to what you mean,
test `2)` above is `element.attr(property, element.attr(property) + 1);

body.append('Prop: '+element.prop(property)+'<br />');
body.append('Attr: '+element.attr(property)+'<hr />');`

If it was normalized when read, would the final line there not output the normalized version?

Comment: Variables: `property = 'action'; body = $('body'); element = $('form');`

Comment: Normalization will only be trigger when **prop** is accessed, and the access of attr will not.

Answer (score 1):

since jquery 1.6.1+ attr() returns/changes property like before 1.6. thus your tests do not make much sense.

be aware of minor changes in return values.

e.g.

attr(‘checked’): before 1.6 true/false is returend, since 1.6.1. “checked”/undefined is returned.

attr(‘selected’): before 1.6 true/false is returned, since 1.6.1 “selected”/undefined is returned

a detailed overview to this topic in german can be found here:

http://mabraham.de/jquery-prop-attr-val-richtig-verwenden/