# jQuery attr vs. prop, there are a list of props?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, prop

This is not a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247058), I need only to decide if the better/fast/correct is to use `attr` or to use `prop`. The simplest and reliable way is checking into a list. A "*list of element-name where the better is use `prop(name)` and/or a list where the better is use `attr(name)`*".

PS: I am using jQuery 1.9+, and suppose that `attr()` is not a deprecated method.

**Example of decisions** (where the *LIST* have the answer):

- is better get ID value by `$(x).prop('id')` or by `$(x).attr('id')`?
- is better change title with `$(x).prop('title','BLABLA')` or with  `$(x).attr('title','BLABLA')`?
- can I use `$(x).attr('selectedIndex')`?
- what property names have risk with "[Cross-browser consistency](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)"?
- there are some case (with Microsoft-IE p.ex.) where `$(x).attr('name')` and `$(x).prop('name')` will return different things?

---

Perhaps a full list is not necessary, only a list of things that make some difference or risk for jQuery.

Edited after close: **please click in the *REOPEN* link below to accept** this edited question text.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/attributes.html

Comment: @roXon: No. That's attributes.

Comment: The "oficial attributes" list (thanks @roXon)  is a good starting point, but perhaps we need only to analyse the jQuery source-code to understand what attributes and/or properties are relevant in this question.

Answer (score 1):

They vary from browser-to-browser, but here's IE's list...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh773183(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element#Properties and also consider that many properties are only available on special types of elements.