# this.class vs. this.getAttribute('class')

Tags: javascript, html

I have a radio button, and when it is pressed a function is called, which accepts the class of the button as an argument. So something like this:

```
<input class="myclass" type="radio" name="name" value="x" checked="true" onClick="myFunction(this.value, this.getAttribute('class'))"></input>
```

Notice that in my onClick, I have `this.getAttribute('class')` instead of simply `this.class`. I tried using this.class but I kept getting `undefined`. Is `this.class` not an acceptable thing to do? I have used `this.id` elsewhere in my code which works fine, but for some reason I need to use `getAttribute` when I want to reference class.

So essentially I am asking what is the difference between `this.class` and `this.getAttribute('class')`?

Comment: `this.class` is incorrect; you intended to access `this.className`.

Comment: Or `classList`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList

Comment: `getAttribute` looks for HTML attributes. Using `this.class` looks for  a JS attribute, which does not exist. The JS equivalent of the HTML `class` attribute is `className`. `class` is also a reserved keyword in JavaScript, so avoid using it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML - attributes vs properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246714/html-attributes-vs-properties)

Comment: thanks all - this.className is indeed what I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use className to get the current value of the class attribute. I think the reason behind this is because class is a reserved word.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `this.class`. i think you mean `this.className`.
see this:

`getAttribute("class")` is more universal, because it can be used in different types of documents. In XML documents, most importantly. Including SVG.

`this.className` works only in HTML

Comment: You haven't cited your quote. Where did you get that from?

Comment: you can see the comparision here http://jsperf.com/classname-vs-getattribute-class