# $('.input:checked') behaves differently than $('.input[checked=checked]')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Take the following scenario: you have 2 radio buttons, both with the same name, and both checked (I realize that's invalid):

```
<input type="radio" class="input" name="cb1" checked="checked" />
<input type="radio" class="input" name="cb1" checked="checked" />
```

Why do the following two selectors behave differently?

```
$('.input:checked').size(); // returns 1
$('.input[checked=checked]').size(); // returns 2
```

Apparently, the first selector returns only the checkbox that occurs last in the markup, while the first selector returns both.

Comment: codepen: http://codepen.io/joelbyrd/pen/atoKk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `:checked` selector checks the `checked` *property* of the elements [which is different from the `checked` *attribute*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246714/html-attributes-vs-properties).

Comment: **property**: Current *state* of the radio buttons (only one can be checked)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the SO link. [This comment specifically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5884994/422845) was helpful in distinguishing between element attributes and properties.

Answer (score 2):

Since both elements have the same name, they function as a single unit with only one radio button is actually selected at the time when elements are rendered.

[image]

`.input[checked=checked]` does not care about results, it just checks the attributes.

`.input:checked` reflect the actual element state.

Change `name`s to differ, and both queries will return `2`.