# Change href in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have next code, but it's don't work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function(){
 var links = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
        links[i].href = 'test.html';
   }
}
</script> 
<ul>
<li><a href = 1.html>1.</a></li>
<li><a href = 2.html>2.</a></li>
<li><a href = 3.html>3.</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to change ALL links, on 'test.html'. Without JQuery.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change this `links[i].href += 'test.html';` to the following:

```
 links[i].setAttrtibute('href','test.html');
```

**Update**

As Mouser have already pointed out below in his comment, this `<a href = 1.html>1.</a>` is not a valid HTML. You have to enclose the value you assign to the `href` in either single or double quotes, like below:

```
<a href = "1.html">1.</a>
```

Comment: `links[i].href = 'test.html'` should also work perfectly though? The HTML isn't valid though. `href = 1.html` should be `href="1.html"`.

Comment: `setAttrtibute` won't work. Both `setAttribute` and `href` property should work. But changing the property is usually prefered than changing the attribute.

Comment: @Mouser Yes. That's actually the correct way. This is related to the old [property vs attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246714/html-attributes-vs-properties) issue.

Comment: @Vohuman thanks for the link. I wasn't aware of this. However, there is one thing I can't get. Isn't the `href` of an anchor an attribute of this element? Thanks

Comment: @Christos You are welcome. Yes, `href` is an attribute. It's used by the DOM for setting of the element's `href` property on page load.  From now on JavaScript should manipulate the properties not attributes. `setAttribute` might work, but it's implementation-specific, it's safer to manipulates the properties directly instead of leaving it to the browser.