# Variable in HTML tag using Angular2

Tags: html, angular, tags

I'm trying to have an independent input for each element that I display thanks to *ngFor in Angular2, I try this but it doesn't work :

```
<li *ngFor="let child of childArray; let i=index"> <input type="checkbox" id="{{child.name}}" style="display:none;">
    <label for="{{child.name}}">
       <h1>{{child.name}}</h1> 
   </label></li>
```

Of course `{{child.name}}` is correctly displayed but it seems I can't use it as a variable in tag component. Does someone have an idea to manage it ?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704671/error-while-adding-for-attribute-to-label-in-angular-2-0-template

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
<li *ngFor="let child of childArray; let i=index">
  <input type="checkbox" [attr.id]="child.name" style="display:none;">
  <label [attr.for]="child.name">
    <h1>{{child.name}}</h1> 
  </label>
</li>
```

When you say "I can't use it as a variable in tag component", what do you mean? The attribute doesn't contain the value?

Comment: Comment from @slidefizz (to preserve it when his "answer" gets deleted):
Thank you for your answer it works with your syntax, by "I can't use it as a variable in tag component" I mean that `id="{{child.name}}` and `for="{{child.name}}"` don't work with this syntax, `for` and `id` being the `tag component` (or maybe "tag attribute" is a better meaning) and `{{child.name}}` the variable.