# Angular2 the for attribute on a label does not link it to the input

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-components

I am working with Angular2 RC5.
I have a component encapsulating a label and an input

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-input',
  template: `
    <div class="mx-field" >
      <label [attr.for]="id"><ng-content></ng-content></label>
      <input
        type='text'
        id = "{{id}}"
      />
    </div>
  `
})

export class InputComponent {
  @Input() id: string;
}
```

It is called from any template as follows `<my-input id="inputcontrol">input</my-input>` 
The problem is that when I click on the label the input does not get focused, although when I check the dev tools in the browser both the for and id attributes are correctly set

here is a plunker showing the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/WGhg597MzJ5df4f0Hm5n

Answer (score 1):

Well I found a hack for now, If I send it using a name other than id it works. ie:

```
import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-input',
  template: `
    <div class="mx-field" >
      <label [attr.for]="ident"><ng-content></ng-content></label>
      <input
        type='text'
        id = "{{ident}}"
      />
    </div>
  `
})

export class InputComponent {
  @Input() ident: string;
}
```

and then from the templates call it `<my-input id="inputcontrol">input</my-input>` this works.

The problem was that the DOM had multiple elements (angular component and the input) with the same id