# removeAttribute deletes "disabled" but not "checked"

Tags: javascript, html

There are two lines from my js code:

```
document.getElementsByName('group')[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
document.getElementsByName('group')[0].removeAttribute('checked');
```

First string works good but second one makes nothing. I want to follow html5 style so setting `false` value for `checked` isn't my choice. 
And by the way I look for method to set empty attrs. Methods from other topics like `.setAttribute(attr_name,"");` do exactly what they are: create attr with empty string value but not just attr. What should I do?

Comment: `.removeAttribute('checked')` seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/c63pkjdx/

Comment: are you sure it doesn't work?

Comment: Why are you playing with attributes instead of changing properties?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in chrome: http://codepen.io/josiahruddell/pen/aZbNLX, do you have a more specific test?

Comment: @Quantastical, your code works

Comment: @vol7ron, I'm sure

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher, as html5 says me. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JosiahRuddell, doesn't work in FF too

Comment: @Antipers007 This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246714/html-attributes-vs-properties

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checked` is a property, you should treat it as such:

```
document.getElementsByName('group')[0].checked = false;
```

Comment: I agree. Attributes have values and as far as I've seen `key=value` type assignation.  Properties are either there or not. You don't need `checked=true` or `checked=checked` etc. People do it and it works I believe because browsers and libraries know that no one understands the actual spec so they help you out. Regardless of it jquery or browsers know fill in the gaps, you should treat it as a property and not a attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify that for me? "Checked" is property, but "disabled" - attribute. Right? It confuses me...

Comment: @Antipers007 Leeish posted a good link that will explain why and what in more details :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html

Comment: @andlrc, sorry, I didn't notice it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I show that your code works. here is the jsfiddle.
Show us your checkbox group.
You will see that when run, the first, aka `[0]` disabled is removed while the input with `value='2'` still is disabled.

https://jsfiddle.net/Esko/m7o0z0gc/

`<input name="group" type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled='disabled' value='1' />
<input name="group" type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled='disabled' value='2' />
<input name="group" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value='3' />`