# Why does JavaScript change src to FQDN?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about Javascript
I ran into a problem with it.

Currently, I am making a game. It's going very well.
But when I try to get the src of a image on this way

```js
document.write(document.getElementById('a').src);
```

```html
<img id="a" src="img.png">
```

it always gives me the FQDN (http://example.com/path/to/file.png), but I entered it without it.
It is very difficult to do some server based checks (because I use the / as delimeter)

Does someone know why this is expected behaviour and how to change the src attribute in JavaScript to the filename instead of the FQDN?

Comment: `.getAttribute("src")`.

Comment: Thanks @Xufox - but I expect that .src is doing the same as getAttribute("src"). Am I wrong?

Comment: Attributes and properties are not the same thing.

Comment: They look like the same, is there a specific reason whhy the chose to do this? It's confusing me a bit.

Comment: Maybe this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246714/html-attributes-vs-properties

Comment: Thanks! That helps me a lot :)