# How can I access a property of an html element?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to get the `"validacion"` property of an HTML element.

```
console.log (element[0]);
```

This returns me:

[image]

```
<input class="estilo_input_text ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" id="asunto" name="asunto" ng-model="asunto" placeholder="Asunto" type="text" validacion="required">
```

How can I access the `"validacion"` property?

Comment: `element.attr('validacion')`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite

Comment: `console.log(element[0].getAttribute("validacion"));`

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez it works!! can you put it as answer please?

Comment: @yavg See me answer. If you need more details, feel free to ask. :)

Comment: FYI, attributes are different to properties. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246714/html-attributes-vs-properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)  [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method:

```
console.log(element[0].getAttribute("validacion"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `element[0].attributes['validacion'].value`

Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `element[0].getAttribute("attribute_name");` method.

Comment: `element` is a jqLite object (or an array) and won't have a `getAttribute` method

Comment: corrected, but even if the query returns an single item array, naming convention dictates the name of the variable should be named "elements"

Comment: @SujalMandal you should change `element[0].getAttribute("attribute_name ");` to  `element[0].getAttribute("attribute_name");`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you need to do this:

You'd better use the directive way to get the element.

Or you can use Angular `jqLite` API:

```
angular.element('#asunto').attr('validacion')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do with **[`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)**:

```
console.log(element[0].getAttribute("validacion"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer you're looking for.

Since you're using `Angular` and you're implementing `ng-model="asunto"` why not make it like this in html.

```
<input class="estilo_input_text ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" id="asunto" name="asunto" ng-model="asunto" placeholder="Asunto" type="text">

<button ng-click="get_model(asunto)"></button>
```

In your JS:

```
$scope.asunto = "model";

$scope.get_model = function (string) {
  console.log(string)
}
```

I think this might work becuase you're already using `ng-model` why not use `ng-model` instead.