# What's the expected behavior of puppeteer's ElementHandle.getProperty()?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Puppeteer 1.0.0-post. The `getProperty()` method seems somewhat magical. For example, if your page contains:

```
<a href="/foo/bar.html">link</a>
```

Then this will return not a *relative* but an *absolute* URL:

```
const propertyHandle = await elementHandle.getProperty('href');
const href = await propertyHandle.jsonValue();
// href is 'https://localhost:8080/foo/bar.html'
```

On the other hand, if you were to do the more roundabout:

```
const hrefHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(element => element.getAttribute('href'), elementHandle);
const href = await hrefHandle.jsonValue();
// href is '/foo/bar.html'
```

As far as I can tell, the puppeteer documentation doesn't mention this behavior of `getProperty()`?

It gets uglier, for instance if you want to get the `style` attribute of an element. It looks like puppeteer's `getProperty()` actually tries to parse the style in some way, which parsing is buggy/incomplete. The only way to get the raw text is with the roundabout call to `evaluateHandle(...)`.

Is this an intended feature and simply a documentation bug? Or is it just, outright, a puppeteer bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [HTML - attributes vs properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246714/html-attributes-vs-properties) for difference between HTML attributes and DOM properties.

You can easily see the difference without Puppeteer, too. For example, on this page:

```
document.getElementById('nav-questions').href    
// returns "https://stackoverflow.com/questions"

document.getElementById('nav-questions').getAttribute('href')    
// returns "/questions"
```