# jQuery Disabled no longer working on my Win8.1 machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, attr, disabled-control

I have (successfully) been using the following on my old Vista machine:

```js
var isIE = isInternetExplorer();

$("#divTablesButton" + (isIE ? "" : " :input"))
    .attr( "disabled", this.m_Array1.length === this.m_Array2.length ? true : false );
```

where `divTablesButton` is a button and `isInternetExplorer` is the function (which still seems to be working fine):

```js
function isInternetExplorer() {
    return ( getInternetExplorerVersion() < 0 ? false : true );
};

function getInternetExplorerVersion() {
    // Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
    // (indicating the use of another browser).
    var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
            rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
    }
    return rv;
};
```

But now I have noticed this does not work on my Win 8.1 machine with the newest versions of IE and Chrome.

Anyone know what is up? To clarify, it's the `attr("disabled"` bit that is wrong. The buttons do not disable.

Comment: .is(":disabled") comment: Surely that is asking if it is disabled rather than just setting it. (I have tried it and it returns false before and after my attempt to disable the button.)

Comment: since its returning false your selector is `#divTablesButton :input` do you really have an input element inside your button? Which one are you trying to disable the button or the input? Also you do not need the ternary stuff for the length comparison as the comparison itself will return a boolean value

Comment: Understand, I forget that one @Rewind. Can you try $('element').prop('disabled', true);

Comment: IE11 now shows 'Netscape' instead of 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11

Comment: Why are you treating modern versions of Internet Explorer differently than Chrome? What problems are you attempting to solve with this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using? In versions >1.6 they want people to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` for properties like `disabled`, `required`, `checked` etc. (things that are booleans). [This older SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051491/difference-between-prop-and-attr-in-jquery-and-when-to-use-attr-and-prop) will explain better than I can.

Try using `prop()` instead like below. Additionally, there's a piece of your code that you can remove. You've written a statement `variable_a === variable_b ? true : false`. The result of `variable_a === variable_b` will always be `true` or `false`, so you don't need the `? true : false` part.

```
var isIE = isInternetExplorer();
$("#divTablesButton" + (isIE ? "" : " :input")).prop("disabled", this.m_Array1.length === this.m_Array2.length);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thats the same I suggest in comment section

Comment: Ha! your comment came in while I was writing my answer.

Comment: True!! no hard feelings @grammar

Comment: Haha I know - hate when that happens. It's a race :D

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the tips. It is now working. I can remember I needed to add " :input" for chrome before, but that is obviously not the case for buttons. So when do I need to add input?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add `:input` anywhere anymore. I'm not sure why you would have needed it in the first place actually, but it depends on what `#divTablesButton` is. Is it a `<button>` or an `<input type="button">`? Regardless, if you are using an id as a selector then you should not need it. Just make sure that the id `divTablesButton` is unique to the page and you'll always be grabbing the same thing.