# JQuery: Check if any radio button is checked using radio button class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I realize similar question had earlier been answered on stack overflow a few times. I checked all the questions and none were similar to mine.

I have a html form that has some radio buttons. In my validation I want to check if atleast one of the radio buttons are checked.

My approach so far:

- All radio buttons have same class
- All radio buttons have same name

I need to

- check if atleast one of the radio button is selecetd
- read the value of selected button.

My Javascript so far

```
function supportFormValidation(){
   var isChecked = $('.radioButton').attr('checked')?true:false;
   alert(isChecked);
   return false;}
```

This always returns false. But when I try to read vale by individual IDs of each radio button it returns true. Is there any way I can check if a radio button is checked by using the class name.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/evj9nch3/

Comment: You mean like http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7rq64ku1/?

Answer (score 2):

Just use :checked.

```
var isChecked = !!($('.radioButton:checked').length);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the `checked` property you need to use the `prop` function (after 1.6 anyways).  Because the value is either true or false, it's considered a property of the element not an attribute.

Nits answer is a better way of doing it, but look below for the reason why your implementation isn't working.

[Take a look at this post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051491/difference-between-prop-and-attr-in-jquery-and-when-to-use-attr-and-prop)

[Here is a link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esaLf2va/1/)

```js
function supportFormValidation() {
  var isChecked = $('.radioButton').prop('checked') ? true : false;
  alert(isChecked);
  return false;
};

supportFormValidation();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' class='radioButton' checked='true' />
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this. I checked this is working**

```
$(".ClassName").prop("checked", true)
```