# Put an id to a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parent-child

I wanted to put an id in my element's parent element. Below is my code:

```
<div>
    <div id="child"></div>
<div>
```

Im aware that jquery has a way to select a parent element , but I dont know how what method shall I use to put an id to it. Below is my jquery code:

```
div_resizable = $( "#child" ).parent();
div_resizable.id = "div_resizable";
```

Above code doesnt work with me. It doesnt throw an error, but no changes had taken effect. Any solution to my problem?

Comment: try `div_resizable.attr("id", "div_resizable");`

Comment: A friendly tip, next time you have an issue, before you ask a question here, use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)s or [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statements to determine what each variable's value is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For achieve what you want, you can use the jquery [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$("#child" ).parent().attr('id', 'newID');
```

Or you can use the [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$("#child" ).parent().prop('id', 'newID');
```

And you can check the difference between the two here: [difference between prop() and attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051491/difference-between-prop-and-attr-in-jquery-and-when-to-use-attr-and-prop)

Answer (score 2):

Of course `div_resizable.id = "div_resizable"` doesn't work. `div_resizeable` is an jQuery array and you are trying to assign `id` to it.

Try [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes) instead:

```
$("#child").parent().attr({id: "div_resizable"});
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a property on the first element inside a jQuery result object:

```
div_resizable = $( "#child" ).parent()[0];
//                                    ^^^
div_resizable.id = "div_resizable";
```

This picks the first [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) from the result so that you can directly access the property.

Or:

```
$('#child').parent().prop('id', 'div_resizable');
```

Use the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) helper method to accomplish the same thing.