# JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.attr('selected') may use property instead of attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#operatordelivery').attr('checked', true);
```

Hi, I am currently working on migrating jQuery version to jQuery-2.1.1 where I could see the warning in the console `JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.attr('selected') may use property instead of attribute`. I didn't get a clear idea of what this warning explains. Can somebody tell me what does this error means?

Comment: https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/94

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From JQMIGRATE docs:

> ### JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.attr('selected') may use property instead of attribute
>
> **Cause**: Prior to jQuery 1.9, $().attr("checked") etc. would sometimes
>   use the checked|selected property instead of the attribute when
>   interacting with non-XML elements, despite the fact that browsers and
>   the HTML specifications allow the properties (current state) to differ
>   from the attributes (initial/default state). This was a holdover from
>   earlier versions of jQuery that did not offer $().prop.
>
> **Solution**: Boolean properties should generally not be passed to
>   $().attr at all; replace with $().prop unless you truly intend to
>   update the underlying HTML attribute.

Ref: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/1.x-stable/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryfnattrselected-might-use-property-instead-of-attribute

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in
>   specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes
>   took property values into account when retrieving some attributes,
>   which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop()
>   method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while
>   .attr() retrieves attributes.

jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Referenced answer of SO: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) and [difference between prop() and attr() in jQuery and when to use attr() and prop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051491/difference-between-prop-and-attr-in-jquery-and-when-to-use-attr-and-prop)

Comment: i read out the document, but still i couldn't get a clear picture about this warning. It would be more helpful if i can get answers from good examples.

Comment: @SasiDunston check the edit, added more resources, it's a deeply explained change

Answer (score 10):

With Jquery version 1.9.1+ instead of

```
$('#operatordelivery').attr('checked', true);
$('#operatordelivery').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

you have to use this one

```
$('#operatordelivery').prop('checked', true);
```

And also, instead of

```
$('#operatordelivery').attr('checked')
```

you have to use :

```
$('#operatordelivery').prop('checked')
```