# Remove "check" after submit

Tags: html, jquery, button, checkbox

I've a "stupid" problem: when I click a specific button, I want to reset the checkbox checked in unchecked.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox">1
<input type="checkbox">2
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

JS

```
jQuery("#resetta").click(function(){
jQuery('input:checked').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The provided answers are correct for checkboxes, but if you intend to make a complete form with other inputs, something like the input type reset may be easier, this is a button to reset the form:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

Comment: Aha... Spotting the wood around the trees :) +1

Comment: Nice old-school (proper) answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.prop('checked',false);` for that

```
jQuery('input:checked').prop('checked',false);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/48/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use .prop() to set the checked property instead of removing the attribute

```
jQuery('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
```

- [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)
- [difference between prop() and attr() in jQuery and when to use attr() and prop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051491/difference-between-prop-and-attr-in-jquery-and-when-to-use-attr-and-prop)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeProp()` instead of `removeAttr()`

```
jQuery('input:checked').removeProp('checked');
```

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for prop vs attr