# Replacing html from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I've such peace of html:

```
<a  control_type="dialog" request_url="/int_studies/json/callback_display_test_task_list" destination_block_id="course-test-dialog" no_check_plain="1" request_data_source="attr" request_data="iduniver_edu_prog=519&amp;course_id=375&amp;idtest=3954&amp;type=1" dialog_title="teeeeeeest" dialog_buttons="{&#039;Закрыть&#039; : function(){ $(this).dialog(&#039;close&#039;); }}" class="ajax-command-anchor" href="#">teeeeeeest &gt;&gt;</a>
```

Using Mozilla Firefox and Greasemonkey-addon I need to replace

> request_url="/int_studies/json/callback_display_test_task_list"

to

> request_url="#"

Greasemonkey executes your javascript-code on linked pages, so how should I access **request_url** parameter value from js? Please, help.

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: Have a look at jquery's attr method: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: now i'm playng with tries inside function $('a').each(function() { }, but I don't know if it's a right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind an event when your dom is ready. You should write your snippet in `document.ready` function. Your snippet would be

```
$(function () {
  $("a[control_type=dialog]").prop("request_url", "#");
})
```

Comment: thanks, also .attr() I found as working. Apperciate!

Comment: Why `prop` over `attr` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Nice question By the way. This link will explain you better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051491/difference-between-prop-and-attr-in-jquery-and-when-to-use-attr-and-prop

Comment: @RayonDabre You can user `attr` as well

Comment: @Vineet, Yes but the point is about **readability** and I dont find `href` as **property**, it is an **attribute**