# Initialisation of value attribute in date tags ignored

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, mobile-safari, android-browser

On iOS and Android, the following code fails to have the `date` tag pre-filled with the text returned by `startOfYear()`.

```html
<input type="date" value="{{startOfYear()}}">
```

For some reason the above, and everything else I tried, worked fine on the desktop browsers, but the mobile ones always just showed cleared, empty inputs.

It's not a variable, I don't need it `watch`d or updated or to have the `input` update so even though I think it would work, it's too much to introduce a `model` just for this.

Answer (score 0):

I really couldn't find anything on this so I'm answering my own question here for you guys.

It turns out the mobile browsers were sticklers for the difference between [setting attributes and using properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16051572/2518317), which I finally realised after I recognised the `input` tag exists in the DOM before angular gets its hands on it (so the default is already set as, literally, `"{{startOfYear()}}"`).

```html
<input type="date" ng-property="{value:startOfYear()}">
```

The solution was just to introduce a new directive for whenever I might need it down the road for unrelated forms that exhibit the same issues.

```js
.directive('ngProperty', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $.each($parse(attrs.ngProperty)(scope), function(prop, value) {
                element.prop(prop, value);
            });
        }
    };
})
```