# JQuery .split() property

Tags: jquery

I have snippets of code that I don't quite understand

```
var row = $(this).prop('id').split('_')[1];
var col = $(this).prop('id').split('_')[2];
```

I'm trying to manipulate checkboxes and they're on a table.
What will be the array value that's gonna be set on variables **row** and **col**?

Comment: Could you please post also the relevant HTML code ? Thanks

Comment: the id of `$(this)` seems to be a string split by two `_`'s - for example `foo_bar_string` - your `row` variable would be set to the 2nd element of the array (`bar`) and your `col` variable would be set to the 3rd element of the array (`string`).

Comment: I don't have access to the HTML code as we are using a template on an API but I have inspected the elements. The id of the elements were Q1_1_1 where Q1_[row]_[col]. And they are inside $(":checkbox").click(function(){});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split is a javascript web API method([Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) and does't have anything to do with jQuery.

In your case it will split the value of the id attribute if it does have a underscore (`_`). split returns and array , so [n] (n being any index of the array) , will return the value of the given index of the array. Eg. in the below example `am` is returned , which has an index of `1`.

So ,

```
   $("#i_am_a_href").attr('id').split('_') // will return [ "i", "am", "a", "href" ]
   $("#i_am_a_href").attr('id').split('_')[1] // will return 'am'
```

See example below

```js
var row = $("#i_am_a_href").attr('id').split('_');
console.log(row);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="i_am_a_href">Anchor Tag</a>
```

Pro Tip : you also probably want to learn the difference between `prop()` and `attr()` , and when to use which (**[LINK HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16051519/4381665)**)