# Check box with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6mk7m/9/

I have found out on stackoverflow that I need to make jsfiddle account so I can show you guys the code for easy reading, ( sorry guys ) if my English is a not so good,

I am currently learning jQuery, I am not an expert, just a " beginner " ,anyway,

I have made a checkbox and I gave it an id = all

```
<input type="checkbox" id="all" /><span style='color:red'>All</span>
```

Simply what I want is, when I click on this checkbox with this specific **id = all** I want to check these 3 checkboxes listed below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="us[]" value="google" />Google
<input type="checkbox" name="us[]" value="youtube" />Youtube
<input type="checkbox" name="us[]" value="friend" />Friend<br/><br/>
```

so this is the code that I some how figured out,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("document").ready(function() {


    $("input[id='all']").bind('click',function(){

        var all = $(this);

        console.log('status: ' + all.prop('checked'));


        if(all.prop('checked') == true)
        {
            //alert('now its true');
            $("input:checkbox").attr("checked","checked");
        }
        else if (all.prop('checked') == false){
            $("input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    })
})  
 </script>
```

when i click on the checkbox with id = all ( **it selects all checkboxes** )

now when I click the second time on the checkbox with id = all ( **it unchecked all checkboxes** )

***every thing is greet untill now***

Now the problem when I go to click a third time on the checkbox with id = all

( **it does not check any checkboxes** )
However when I check the console I see all attributes equal to checked - but the checkboxes I don't see them checked on the browser I mean the checkboxes they don't have this **tick** mark in the middle of each box,
maybe there is something wrong with code, I just can't figure it out why it's not working when I want to click more than 3 times.

Comment: Do not use `attr`, use `prop`. To check, call `$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);`, to uncheck, change `true` to `false`

Comment: Corrected your jsFiddle; you forgot to include jQuery in the external resources.

Comment: @user2237771, I corrected my comment. I'm sorry, but I was wrong the first time.

Comment: anton i just did that , the same thing,

Comment: and i have linked sjFiddle with jquery external resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle with the correct behavior.  As of the most recent versions of jQuery the command prop() should be used to alter properties of an element (as opposed to attributes).

http://jsfiddle.net/6mk7m/10/

See the code below:

```
    if(all.prop('checked') == true)
    {
        //alert('now its true');
        $("input:checkbox").prop("checked",true);
    }
    else if (all.prop('checked') == false){
        $("input:checkbox").prop("checked",false);
    }
```

Comment: thanks man for the help, but i just want to know why the attr method dose not work...? until i use the .prop method

Comment: Rather than give my own explanation; consider giving this question and answer a read over if you are curious http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247058/jquery-attr-vs-prop

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#all').on('click', function(){
    $('input:checkbox[name="us[]"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selecctall').click(function(event) {  //on click 
        if(this.checked) { // check select status
            $('.checkbox1').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = true;  //select all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"               
            });
        } else {
            $('.checkbox1').each(function() { //loop through each checkbox
                this.checked = false; //deselect all checkboxes with class "checkbox1"                       
            });         
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be great if you add a bit of explanation to your code, especially the key things used in it and how they help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way-

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/6mk7m/12/)

```
$("input[id='all']").bind('click',function(){
        var all = $(this);
        console.log('status: ' + all.prop('checked'));
        if(all.is(':checked')){
            //alert('now its true');
            $("input:checkbox[name^='us']").prop("checked",true);
        }
        else{
            $("input:checkbox[name^='us']").prop("checked",false);
        }
});
```

Comment: yes, i saw that mohammed , but on my firefox browser it dose not work, but the console shows the attributes are having the vale of checked

Comment: thanks Mohammed for you help, but there is somebody else just before you solve it out, so i had to mark his answer, the correct one, i really appreciated your help, thank you one more time.....

Answer (score 0):

why not make it super simple:

```
$('#all').on("change",function(){
    $('input:checkbox').not('#all').each(function(a,b){
           var _checked=$('#all').is(":checked");
          $(b).prop('checked',_checked)
        });
});
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mk7m/17/)