# How to continue perform click event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

first time, On page load,  I click on deluxe and the click event was successful.
However, after I click on another option and again click on the deluxe option, the click event was not successful.

How do I get it to work ?

Here is my code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A Basic Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        A Basic Form</h1>
    <hr>
    <form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Car Trim and Package Information</legend>
        <div class="form-field">
            <div>
                Package:
            </div>
            <input id="plain" type="radio" name="trim" value="plain">
            <label for="plain">
                Plain</label>
            <input id="deluxe" type="radio" name="trim" value="deluxe">
            <label for="deluxe">
                Deluxe</label>
            <input id="custom" type="radio" name="trim" value="custom">
            <label for="custom">
                Custom</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <div>
                Extra Options:</div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="foglights" name="option" value="foglights">
            <label for="foglights">
                Fog Lights</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="leather" name="option" value="leather">
            <label for="leather">
                Leather</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="dvd" name="option" value="dvd">
            <label for="dvd">
                DVD</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Form">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[name='trim']").click(function (event) {
                if ($(this).val() == "deluxe") {
                    $("input[name='option']").attr("checked", true);
                } else if ($(this).val() == "plain") {
                    $("input[name='option']").attr("checked", false);
                }
            });
            $("input[name='option']").click(function (event) {
                $("#custom").attr("checked", "checked");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _how to call click event work continue_ Couldn't get you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

the reason behind why `attr()` is not working is,

The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before **jQuery 1.6**, the `.attr()` method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior.

so, As of **jQuery 1.6**, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

and your final code will be,

```
$("input[name='trim']").click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).val() == "deluxe") {
        $("input[name='option']").prop('checked', true);
    } else if ($(this).val() == "plain") {
        $("input[name='option']").prop('checked', false);
    }
});
$("input[name='option']").click(function (event) {
    $("#custom").prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name='trim']").click(function(event) {
        if ($(this).val() == "deluxe") {
            $("input[name='option']").prop("checked",true);
        } else if ($(this).val() == "plain") {
            $("input[name='option']").prop("checked",false);
        }
    });
    $("input[name='option']").click(function(event) {
        $("#custom").prop("checked", true);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TsZTv/)

also [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247058/jquery-attr-vs-prop)