# Find the id by class in nested div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, mouseevent

I have an html like this

```
<div class='click' id='1'>
one
<div class='click' id='2'>
    two
    <div class='click' id='3'>
        three
        <div class='click' id='4'>
            four
            <div class='click' id='5'>
                five
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

if i have and click event on class click ,there is any way to return the id of which i click 
such as 
$('.click').click(function(){
   alert('id whitch i click')

});
Becase if i click on three i allway get the id of one and two three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just do this:

```
$('.click').click(function(e){ //e=event
    alert($(this).attr("id")); // alert clicked element's id
    e.stopPropagation(); // stop event propagation so it doesnt propagate to click 1 and click 2
})
```

**Update**: As mentioned by Felix Kling, you can access de DOM directly and use:

```
alert(this.id);
```

Comment: And getting the ID is even easier by accessing the property directly  on the DOM element: `this.id`.

Answer (score 2):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tzJUN/ using `this.id` http://jsfiddle.net/c65x9/

If you keen : [jQuery attr vs prop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247058/jquery-attr-vs-prop)

Stop propogation will stop the `click` event the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

API:

- `.stoppropagation` - http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.click').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert($(this).prop("id")); //<< --- or this.id

    });

});
```

Comment: thanh you so much my day is save ♥

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.click').click(function(e){ 
    $(this).attr("id"); 
alert($(this).attr("id"));//here you can see your clicked id

})
```

Comment: Without preventing the event `e` from bubbling how many alerts would you expect to see if "five" were clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. its simple

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.click').click(function(){
var ID=$(this).attr('id');
alert(ID);
//This ID varible will return ID of the Div Clicked
});
});
```