# Coffeescript evaluates only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, coffeescript

I want to make a select all checkbox based on [this findle](http://jsfiddle.net/FAYJS/378/). I made a coffeescript like this:

```
$(document).on 'click','.select_all_clans', ->
  if $(this).is(':checked')
    $('.clan_checkbox').attr 'checked', true
```

But it works only when the check_box.clan_checkbox was not selected earlier, and it checks them only once.

This is my form:

```
<%= form_tag show_schools_path do %>
 <p>
   Wybierz klan/y: 
   Feniks: <%= check_box_tag 'clans[]','Feniks', (true if !@clans.nil? and @clans.include? 'Feniks'), class: "clan_checkbox" %>,
   Jednorożec: <%= check_box_tag 'clans[]','Jednorożec', (true if !@clans.nil? and @clans.include? 'Jednorożec'), class: "clan_checkbox" %>,
   Krab: <%= check_box_tag 'clans[]', 'Krab', (true if !@clans.nil? and @clans.include? 'Krab'), class: "clan_checkbox" %>,
   Lew: <%= check_box_tag 'clans[]', 'Lew', (true if !@clans.nil? and @clans.include? 'Lew'), class: "clan_checkbox" %>,
   Zaznacz Wszystkie: <%= check_box_tag 'select_all', 'nil', false, class: "select_all_clans" %>
 </p>
<%= submit_tag "Szukaj!" %>
<% end %>
```

I think  this is becouse of this `(true if !@clans.nil? and @clans.include? 'Lew')`evaluation.

I am just starting learning CS so pleasemake full explain if possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, I hope that this is what you are looking for:

```
boxes = $('#checkboxlist [type=checkbox]')
selectAll = $('.selectall')    
toggleCheckboxes = ->    
    if $(this).is ':checked' then boxes.prop "checked", true else boxes.prop "checked", false

selectAll.on 'click', toggleCheckboxes
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FAYJS/429/)

You should change `attr()` to `prop()`.

Nothing special happening here, we have just bound `toggleCheckboxes()` to click event on `selectAll` element.

Tip: next time add `javascript` tag for issues like this, you'll get your solution much faster and u can convert it back to CS later.

Comment: I needed to start from $(document).on 'click', '.selectall' but changing from attr() to prop() done the job. By the way can you explain why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247058/jquery-attr-vs-prop and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr