# Can't deselect checkbox (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I've got 2 checkboxes, if you check one box the other box will be deselected. But for some reason I can't deselect the box that has been checked

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function () {
    jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").removeClass('selected').attr('checked', false);
    jQuery("input[type='checkbox']").parent().removeClass('selected');
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('selected')
    jQuery(this).attr('checked', true);
  });
```

Any idea why this is happening?

**solution (thanks to Shree)**

```js
$('input.example').on('change', function() {
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
  $('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  $('input.example').parent().removeClass('selected');
  $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
}
else
{
  $('input.example').parent().removeClass('selected');
}
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="example" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="example" />
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using a checkbox for this? Use radio buttons with the same name and you don't even need any JS code

Comment: Do you have the HTML as well? Or could you set up an example here: https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Accept ans rather then post in question section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use class with not selector.

```js
$('input.example').on('change', function() {
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
  $('input.example').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  $('input.example').parent().removeClass('selected');
  $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
}
else
{
  $('input.example').parent().removeClass('selected');
}
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="example" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="example" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is almost working for me. If you uncheck the checked box then the class won't be removed. It's been removed if you click the other box.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, If you want to set the "Checked" property in "input" with type "checkbox", You need use:

```
$('input#id').prop('checked', true);
```

or

```
$('input#id').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: I've changed .attr('checked', false); to .prop('checked', false); and attr('checked', true); to .prop('checked', true); but that doesn't work..

I wan't check/uncheck a box, if a box is checked then uncheck the other box and I want to add a class to the parent label.

Answer (score 0):

This explains the history of "attr" vs "prop" in jquery well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13247188/3514785

1): Use "prop" to select/deselect checkboxes

2): attr("checked",false) would not remove "checked" but rather give it the value "false". If you really wanted to use "attr" you should rather use removeAttr... As in removeAttr("checked").