# Jquery .val() work to set value for textbox but .attr() does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```js
//does not work
$("#TextBoxID1").attr("value","HI Value Change")
//work fine
$("#TextBoxID2").val("HI Value Change")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="TextBoxID1"/>
<input type="text" id="TextBoxID2"/>
```

I want to set value for textbox but jquery `.attr()` does not work while if I try `.val()` it works fine.

I am using angular-autocomplete and in its input control I want to set the value using jquery it works but I just want to know why `.attr()` does not work.

Comment: use `.text()` or `.html()`. can you add html mark up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery attr vs prop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247058/jquery-attr-vs-prop)

Comment: With your snippet changed to be a [mcve], both methods appear to work for me (Chrome)

Comment: your code working fine in your question. LOL :):)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's maybe just a problem with your internet browser.

The `.attr()` method works well for your example:-

https://jsfiddle.net/376a1hjj/

Try to run your code with another browser like chrome or firefox if it isn't the case or update your current browser.